# Is it possible to install Ruby 1.9.3-p327 on OS X Mavericks? And if so, how?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm setting up a Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.3 system for development.

Due to some legacy code and environments on OTHER machines, I need to use Ruby 1.9.3-p327.

However, it isn't building.

**I have Xcode 5.1.1 (5B1008) installed and command line tools are installed.**

I have gcc...

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

The error I'm getting is below.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p327               
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p327 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p327.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p327 to /Users/username/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327 - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #applying patch /Users/username/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/username/.rvm/log/1400875609_ruby-1.9.3-p327/make.log
f_rational_new_no_reduce1(VALUE klass, VALUE x)
^
6 warnings generated.
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
regparse.c:582:15: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'st_index_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return t->num_entries;
    ~~~~~~ ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [regparse.o] Error 1
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I'm finding that ruby-1.9.3-p547 does install without errors, but I need the other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not neccesary to use rvm to install this version of ruby, you can use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). I just installed this exactly version without any problems. And it's easy to install it with `brew`.

If it won't work, then the problem in another place.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the answer. Perhaps I'll give rbenv a try if nothing else works. But I have zero familiarity with rbenv or Homebrew.

Comment: Brew is awesome tool, installs in [one line](http://brew.sh/#install), then `brew install rbenv ruby-build` and `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile` [link](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x), reload bash and then `rbenv uninstall 1.9.3-p327`

Comment: Thanks, again. However, I'm not sure switching Ruby version managers will help. Meanwhile, installing two completely unfamiliar tools could potentially introduce a whole new set of problems. Right now I'm Googling these errors. After I install Homebrew and rbenv, then I could just end up Googling a different set of errors. As I said, I am open to trying Homebrew and rbenv as a last resort, but before that, I'm wondering if anyone has any advice relating to my current setup.